# STS(Spring Tool Suite) and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, ide

Now I am trying to learn about **Spring** step-by-step and read [Pro Spring 3](http://www.apress.com/9781430241072) ebook. In this book, the author describes [STS](http://spring.io/tools/sts). Now I am using with [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/) and I would like to know about **Spring Tool Suite (STS)**.

1). What are the benefits of using it rather than Eclipse IDE
2). Have there any special features for **Spring** on it? 
3). Is the same Extensions tab of Dashboard on STS and Eclipse market-place?

Please describes to me some useful tips (if has pros and cons) on each.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also install the STS plug-ins into you existing Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes I know , but I would like to know has another addition features with STS ? If not why would we choose STS IDE ?

Comment: This is just to make things simple for people who don't already have Eclipse installed.

Comment: @greg-449 is it answer ? If so , I can choose as I want... Hmm...I expect and I want to know about benefits of using STS rather than Eclipse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**STS is just a preconfigured eclipse. it is completely free for any purpose.**

The pros and cons using STS go hand in hand: it has some plugines preinstalled which might be usefull or simply slow your IDE down. It has stuff you might need and don't need to download but i might has stuff you won't need. as far as i know, you can install all plug-ins that STS has in your eclipse.

I find it easier to set up a spring based project with STS. But if you are developing on an existing project it doesn't matter if you use STS or eclipse.

It depends on what you want.

Comment: Do you mean I can choose either Eclipse or STS as I wish and there haven't any special things on both ?

Comment: By using STS , can it support more features with Spring rather than Eclipse that Eclipse can't ?

Comment: If so ,sorry for my stupid this question ... **Why Spring org create this IDE ?**

Comment: you can chose what ever you want. but customizing your eclipse takes time. when working with spirng applications, i would always use STS. to get the spring support you have with the STS takes a lot of configuration

Comment: i personally only use STS, even if i'm not working with spring and just plain java

Comment: spring tool suite also has maven and vfabric-tc-server

Comment: @jos my GWT project , it has no additional server. In my Spring MVC project , I use Tomcat-7. After download and installed sts, I got **vfabric-tc-server** . What about it sir ?

Comment: @jos both is also available for eclipse

Comment: http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/2.5/getting-started/htmlsingle/getting-started.html#intro-tcserver-features

Comment: @PhilippSander yes maven and vfabric-tc-server is avilable for eclipse but when you download sts you know need to configure for maven

Comment: yes. as i said there are pros and cons of features out of the box. pro is: if you need them you have them. con: if you don't need them they take ressources

Comment: I am using STS4 with the Gradle project, after building I am not finding libs/ xyz.jar files inside the build folder. how to view it.